# Getting error when using timestamp index in dask with snowflake

Tags: dask, dask-dataframe

I am trying read tables from snowflake and use merge_asof to perform point in time correct join. Here is the corresponding code:

```
next_failure = dd.read_sql_table('vm_next_failure', conn_url, index_col='ts')
errors = dd.read_sql_table('vm_errors', conn_url, index_col='ts')

ndf = dd.merge_asof(next_failure, errors, left_index=True, right_index='ts', by="machineid", suffixes=("_l", "_r"), allow_exact_matches=False)
```

Here is the error I get:

```
ProgrammingError: (snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError) 252004: Failed processing pyformat-parameters: 255001: Binding data in type (timestamp) is not supported.
[SQL: SELECT vm_errors.ts, vm_errors.machineid, vm_errors.error1, vm_errors.error2, vm_errors.error3, vm_errors.error4, vm_errors.error5 
FROM vm_errors 
WHERE vm_errors.ts >= %(ts_1)s AND vm_errors.ts <= %(ts_2)s]
[parameters: {'ts_1': Timestamp('2015-01-01 06:00:00'), 'ts_2': Timestamp('2016-01-01 05:00:00')}]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/f405)
```

Any thoughts on how to workaround this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to replace Timestamp with TO_Timestamp.
Please run the following query in the snowflake:

```
select TO_Timestamp('2016-01-01 05:00:00')
```

Comment: So TO_TIMESTAMP works in snowflake, however I am not generating the query. The query is being generated by Dask dataframe.read_sql_table(). What I am providing is the table name and the index column name (Which in the database is of type timestamp)